# Matlab simulink c sfunction for DirectFeedThrough showing unexpected results

Tags: c, matlab, simulink

I need a matlab simulink block which involves some simple math calculations.As a first step i made a block which takes input from a constant block and produce it in the output port.I took the code directly from matlab examples.It is **level-2  c sfunction**
Here is the mdlouputs function

```
static void mdlOutputs(SimStruct *S, int_T tid)
{
    int_T element;
    int_T portWidth = ssGetInputPortWidth(S,0);
    InputRealPtrsType uPtrs = ssGetInputPortRealSignalPtrs(S,0);
    real_T *y = ssGetOutputPortSignal(S,0);

    for (element=0; element<portWidth; element++) {
        y[element] = *uPtrs[element];
    }


}
```

But i am getting weird ouputs from the block

here is the result
**I am expecting an output equal to input**

```
when const block(input) is 1  output is 1.875
                           2            2
                           3            2.125
                           10           2.563  etc.
```

I can't figure out the issue

Comment: What is your input data type? It should be double precision for this code to work as expected.

Comment: I cannot see anything wrong with mdlOutputs. Next step would be to debug this using a debugger or simple print statements inside this function to see whether you are receiving your inputs correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have ssSetInputPortDirectFeedThrough set correctly in mdlInitializeSizes.  In your case it appears that it should be

`ssSetInputPortDirectFeedThrough(S, 0, 1)`

otherwise uPtrs is giving you gibberish.

Phil.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I have set directfeedthrough already.any other possibilities?

Comment: The code you've shown looks fine.  So we'd need to see more of it see what else is going on.  As others have indicted, either put some print statements in here to check the input values, or hook the code up to a debugger and step through it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.I have printed the input to file..it is showing the previous results.So it is a problem with input.Then i swapped the constant block with a sine block..I am getting an oscillating signal BUT NOT THE EXPECTED SINE WAVE..